# Parse two-dimensional JSON arrays in bash

Tags: json, bash, parsing

I am currently somehow frustated because I confused how to parse JSON in bash.

I do a basic cURL request to a restful API in the bash script and get a JSON array as response, which is looking like this with multiple entries:

`[{"id":"012.mp4","language":"en","timestamp":1407517051,"name":"012.mp4"},{"id":"013.mp4","language":"en","timestamp":1407512051,"name":"013.mp4"}]`

Now I have to parse this JSON array in my Bash script. My goal is to loop over all entries and (w)get the ressource specified with "name". So in this example above I would like to

`wget 012.mp4`

`wget 013.mp4`

I would appreciate *any* tips or snippets how to archive that. I don't even have any clue how to do it, I read something about using python but I have no idea of python.

Comment: Here's the library for this: https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh — should let you start towards your aim.

Comment: The reason that using python (or ruby or any other scripting language with packages for that matter) is a good idea is that they have packages that provide JSON parsing and give you higher level data structures to work with. I highly encourage you to use a different language than bash to do this, the effort will probably be less in the end than figuring out how to do it correctly with bash.

Comment: This doesn't look like a two-dimensional array to me at all -- it's a one-dimensional array with objects (dictionaries/hashes) inside.

Comment: `in bash` what would you want to do that to yourself? Using any higher level scripting language would make this so easy and clear and readable.

Comment: @njzk2, is the solution I gave none of those things? Bash would be unsuited if you wanted to work with arbitrary data structures (as its dictionaries and arrays don't nest without some severe hackery I'm loathe to go into), but that isn't the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) tool provides an easy-to-use JSON parser for bash:

```
while read -r name; do
  wget "$name"
done < <(curl http://your.url/ | jq -r .[].name)
```

---

You can test this directly:

```
jq -r .[].name <<<'[{"name": "hello"}, {"name": "world"}]'
```

returns:

```
hello
world
```

Comment: that actually does not look half bad!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want full blown json parsing, for such simple file you can also hack something quick and dirty like:

```
sed -En -e 's/}/\n/' -e 's/.*name":"(.*mp4)".*/\1/p' < file.json
```

Also you can try `json_reformat` command and then pass to sed for extracting the values.

Answer (score 0):

Pure BASH --- just for fun:

```
#!/bin/bash

string='[{"id":"012.mp4","language":"en","timestamp":1407517051,"name":"012.mp4"},{"id":"013.mp4","language":"en","timestamp":1407512051,"name":"013.mp4"}]'

string2="${string//\},\{/ }"
oldifs="$IFS"; IFS=' '
array=( $string2 )
IFS="$oldifs"

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
after_last_colon="${i##*:}"
echo "wget ${after_last_colon//[\}\]]/}"
done <<< "$array"
```

Result:

```
wget "012.mp4"
wget "013.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I created my own `jq` using `python`. With `python` we can import the `json` content into a dictionary. Then, we use python syntax to access any portion of the dictionary.

- `data` - pretty print the JSON
- `len( data )` - 2
- `data[ 0 ][ 'name' ]` - 012.mp4
- `data[ 1 ][ 'name' ]` - 013.mp4

Here's a working demo:

```sh
sample() {
  cat <<EOF
[{"id":"012.mp4","language":"en","timestamp":1407517051,"name":"012.mp4"},{"id":"013.mp4","language":"en","timestamp":1407512051,"name":"013.mp4"}]
EOF
}

jq_py() {
cat <<EOF
import json, sys
data = json.load( sys.stdin )
print( json.dumps( $1, indent = 4 ) )
EOF
}

jq() {
  python -c "$( jq_py "$1" )"
}

unquote_py() {
cat <<EOF
import json,sys
print( json.load( sys.stdin ) )
EOF
}

unquote() {
  python -c "$( unquote_py )"
}

sample | jq "data"
# [
#     {
#         "timestamp": 1407517051,
#         "id": "012.mp4",
#         "language": "en",
#         "name": "012.mp4"
#     },
#     {
#         "timestamp": 1407512051,
#         "id": "013.mp4",
#         "language": "en",
#         "name": "013.mp4"
#     }
# ]

sample | jq "len( data )"
# 2

sample | jq "data[ 0 ][ 'name' ]" | unquote
# 012.mp4

sample | jq "data[ 1 ][ 'name' ]" | unquote
# 013.mp4
```